# How can I access svg definitions in a separate file?

Tags: svg

I want to create many svg files that produce output based on a common set of svg definitions, without repeating the definitions in each file. How can I put all the definitions in a single file and access them from the many files?

I believe I should be able to use the `<use href=...>` construct, but I can't get it to work. I have reduced the problem to the following simple example.

The file int.svg contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" stroke="black"/>
<defs> <g id="g"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" fill="none"/> </g> </defs>
<use href="#g"/>
</svg>
```

My (Brave) browser correctly displays this as a circle with a horizontal diameter.
If I extract the definition of the circle into the file def.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<defs> <g id="g"> <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" fill="none"/> </g> </defs>
</svg>
```

then I can try to access this via the file ext.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" stroke="black"/>
<use href="def.svg#g"/>
</svg>
```

but my browser only shows ext.svg as the diameter -- no circle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The diameter is the path not the <use>

Comment: Correct, and the diameter appears in both cases. The <use> is the circle, and only gets drawn in the int.svg case, where the definition is inline.

Comment: Are you using a web server? You'll need to access the files via http or https and not via the filesystem directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sprites for your task.
Read the article: [SVG `use` with External Reference, Take 2](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="110" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red">
<defs>
<g id="g">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" stroke="black"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
</g>  
</defs>  
 <use href="#g"/> 
   <use x="110" y="0" href="#g" stroke-width="4"/> 
     <use x="220" y="0" href="#g" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="5 5"/>
</svg>
```

**- Using presentation styles for different sprite fragments**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="110" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" style="border:1px solid red">
<defs> 
<symbol id="c1" viewBox="0 100 100">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"/>
</symbol>   
  <symbol id="c1" viewBox="0 110 110">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
</symbol>   
  <symbol id="c2" viewBox="0 100 100">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" stroke="black" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  fill="none"/>
</symbol>  
</defs>  
 <use href="#c1" stroke="black" fill="none"/> 
   <use x="110" y="0" href="#c2" stroke-width="4" stroke="orange"/> 
     <use x="220" y="0" href="#c2" stroke="green"  stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="5 5" />
</svg>
```

**- Using External Styles**

First you must remove all internal styles from the sprite: fill, stroke and etc

```css
#c1 {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
}
#c2 {
fill:none;
stroke:orange;
stroke-width:4;
}  

 #c3 {
fill:none;
stroke:green;
stroke-width:4; 
 stroke-dasharray:5 5;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="350" height="110" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" style="border:1px solid red">
<defs> 

  <symbol id="c1" viewBox="0 110 110">
<path d="M 0 50 L 100 50" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
</symbol>   
  <symbol id="c2" viewBox="0 100 100">
   <path d="M 0 50 L 100 50"  />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
 </symbol>   
    <symbol id="c3" viewBox="0 100 100">
       <path d="M 0 50 L 100 50"  />
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
    </symbol>  
</defs>  
 <use href="#c1"/> 
   <use x="110" y="0" href="#c2"/> 
     <use x="220" y="0" href="#c3" />
</svg>
```

- The sprite with the definition of the circles must be placed on the
  server. Code fragments from it can be called anywhere in your project
  by specifying the name of the sprite file and the unique identifier
  of the desired fragment **`<use href="def.svg#с1"/>`**

```css
#c1 {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
}
#c2 {
fill:none;
stroke:orange;
stroke-width:4;
}  

 #c3 {
fill:none;
stroke:green;
stroke-width:4; 
 stroke-dasharray:5 5;
}
.p1 {
stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" >
<defs> 

  <symbol id="c1" viewBox="0 110 110">

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
</symbol>   
  <symbol id="c2" viewBox="0 100 100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
 </symbol>   
    <symbol id="c3" viewBox="0 100 100">
             <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48"  />
    </symbol>  
</defs>  

</svg>  

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <path class="p1" d="M 0 50 L 100 50" /> 
    <use href="#c1"/> 
</svg> 
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <path class="p1" stroke-width="4" d="M 0 50 L 100 50" /> 
    <use href="#c2"/> 
  </svg> 
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
  <path class="p1" d="M 0 50 L 100 50" /> 
    <use href="#c3"/> 
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be a hefty and complex SVG if you need to (pre)define everything with `symbol` and `use` for more than 3 circles

If you are not in the *anti-javascript* camp,
a modern *native* Web Component can **create SVG *client-side***

So you can write declarative HTML:

```html
<svg-circle></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="red"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle path circle-stroke-width="15"></svg-circle>
```

All code required:

```js
customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback(){
    let circleStroke = this.getAttribute("circle-stroke") || "black";
    let circleStrokeWidth = this.getAttribute("circle-stroke-width") ||1;
    let circleStrokeDasharray = this.getAttribute("circle-stroke-dasharray") || 100;
    let r = 40;
    this.innerHTML = `<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">` +
    `<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="${r}" fill="none"
             stroke="${circleStroke}" 
             stroke-width="${circleStrokeWidth}" 
             stroke-dasharray="${circleStrokeDasharray}" pathLength="100"/>` +
    (this.hasAttribute("path") ? `<path stroke="black" d="M 0 50 L 100 50" />` : "") +
    `</svg>`;
  }
});
```

```css
svg-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<svg-circle></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="red"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle path circle-stroke="yellow" circle-stroke-width="15"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="blue" circle-stroke-width="10" circle-stroke-dasharray="5 5"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle path circle-stroke-width="10" circle-stroke-dasharray="5 10"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="pink" circle-stroke-width="7"></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="rebeccapurple" circle-stroke-width="20" path></svg-circle>
<svg-circle circle-stroke="rebeccapurple"></svg-circle>
```